# Get records where associated records name contain a string AND associated record count is bigger than threshold

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select, group-by

I have the following tables:

```
houses 
users
custom_values
```

A user has a FK to house (house_id) - A house has many users
A custom_value has a FK to house (house_id) - A house has many custom values

I want to get all the (distinct) houses that:

- have at least 1 associated `custom_value` which `name` column contains the string 'red' (case insensitive) AND the custom_value column `type` value is 'mandatory'.
- have at least 100 associated users which status column is 'active'

How can I run this query in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could two correlated subqueries: one with `exists` on `custom_values`, the other with a inequality condition on the number of related `users`:

```
select h.*
from houses
where 
    exists (
        select 1 
        from custom_values cv 
        where cv.house_id = h.house_id and cv.type = 'mandatory' and lower(cv.name) = 'red'
    )
    and (
        select count(*) 
        from users u 
        where u.house_id = h.house_id and u.status = 'active'
    ) >= 100
```

Comment: Thanks GMB. This is my bad because I should have edited the question, so I'm happy to accept this answer BUT how would I select the number of users in that house when using a subquery?

Comment: I have created another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61750016/condition-on-count-of-associated-records-in-sql