# Condition on count of associated records in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select, group-by

I have the following tables (with given columns):

```
houses (id)
users (id, house_id, active)
custom_values (name, house_id, type)
```

I want to get all the (distinct) houses and the count of associated users that:

- have at least 1 associated `custom_value` which `name` column contains the string 'red' (case insensitive) AND the custom_value column `type` value is 'mandatory'.
- have at least 100 associated users which status column is 'active'

How can I run this query in PostgreSQL?

Right now I have this query (which was answered in [Get records where associated records name contain a string AND associated record count is bigger than threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61749305/get-records-where-associated-records-name-contain-a-string-and-associated-record)), but I don't know how to select the count of users too (:

```
select h.*
from houses
where 
    exists (
        select 1 
        from custom_values cv 
        where cv.house_id = h.house_id and cv.type = 'mandatory' and lower(cv.name) = 'red'
    )
    and (
        select count(*) 
        from users u 
        where u.house_id = h.house_id and u.status = 'active'
    ) >= 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn the subquery to a lateral join:

```
select h.*, u.no_users
from houses h
cross join lateral (
    select count(*) no_users
    from users u 
    where u.house_id = h.house_id and u.status = 'active'
) u
where 
    u.cnt >= 100
    and exists (
        select 1 
        from custom_values cv 
        where cv.house_id = h.house_id and cv.type = 'mandatory' and lower(cv.name) = 'red'
    )
```

Comment: Awesome. I've also solved it doing a HAVING(count...)) > 100